# ASP.NET Core Route inside controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to route url with and without parameter to two different methods but for some reason it always start first one.

Here is controller code:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    [Route("")]
    [Route("Product")] //If i delete this one then it works how it is intended
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        //It always start this one
        ....
    }

    [Route("Product/{GroupID?}")]
    public IActionResult Index(int GroupID)
    {
        ....
    }        
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure but the problem could happen because the second route contains a nullable {`GroupID?`}.

Comment: Not sure what doesn't work for but I tested this example and `/Product` hits first `Index` and `/Product/77` hits second one

Comment: Oh... Thanks... I was typing `/Product?GrupaID=77`